# Cats-effect 3 - IO hangs after a while in concurrent fs2 streams

Tags: scala, blocking, cats-effect, jstack, fs2

- I'm trying to run a `fs2` application in a `gcp e2-small, 0.5 vCPUs` core machine. Therefore I'm seeing only `io-compute-0` & `io-compute-1` thread names in the logs.
- In the application,

  - There are 2 `fs2.Stream`s that run `concurrently`
  - **Stream 1:** read credentials from a `Ref.of[F, SessionInfo]`
  - call a REST api, do some processing on that data
  - save to disk as a zip file
  - also save some data in to a `Ref.of[F,MyDTO]`
  - This happens every 3 seconds.
  - **Stream 2:** read from `Ref.of[F,MyDTO]` and save some data into another file in the disk.
  - This stream runs every `281 seconds`
- I'm using `AsyncHttpClientCatsBackend` with a connection timeout of `1 minute` but I don't see any timeouts even after few hours of hanging
- I use `Sync[F].blocking` whenever I read/write files from disk.
- After an hour or so the application hangs & below are some images from the thread dump that I took with `jstack`

I would appreciate any help to understand the issue.

[image: runing methods]

[image: io-compute threads]

Both are `awaiting notification on [ 0x00000000e0ddac58 ] which is WorkStealingThreadPool`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A thread dump isn't super helpful, try getting a fiber dump https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/core/fiber-dumps

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not answerable without actually seeing the code or other debugging info, and OP seems to no longer be interested